# Bounding Multiple Matches With Single Text

Tags: regex

I'm trying to parse out the properties of a type (eg. the words 'Cusip', 'Issuer', and 'Coupon') shown here:

```
Public Type GetPricesResponse
    Cusip          As String
    Issuer         As String
    Coupon         As String
End Type
```

The regex `([a-zA-Z0-9]+).+As` works great for this code snippet (see http://regexr.com?300fl), but may not work when mixed with a larger body of code.  So, I've tried to "bound" this regex with the words `Public Type` on the front, and `End Type` at the end to specifically identify what I need as follows:

```
Public\sType\s([a-zA-Z0-9]+).+As.+End\sType
```

...but of course it then doesn't match anything.

I have the MultiLine option set as well.

Comment: You're best off using two regexes, one to match the type declaration, then another to repeatedly match properties within the captured part of the previous regex.

Comment: I like the simplicity of this.  But this adds a complication to the engine I wish to create.  While this example takes 2 regex'es to find the text in question, then a different example could require 4 regex'es, or possibly more.
I was hoping to get an all-in-one solution to simplify things. Since "(\w+ )as" matches all 3 attributes perfectly, then why doesn't "Type\.+(\w+ )as\.+End" match them as well? Is this a shortfall in the RegEx engine's logic, or a shortfall in the logic in my brain? (don't answer that!) If you could explain the reasoning why this doesn't work, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: You only have one `(\w+ )` in your regex; so, it only matches part of the string. Even if you made the inner part repeat, though, you'll only succeed in determining whether the string as a whole matches -- there's no way to get the all the values of repeated group captures out (that's a limitation of regexes). Explanation of exactly what your original regex does: Starts by finding the first occurrence of 'Public Type '. Then matches as many alphanumeric characters as it can from that location (and captures them in a group). `.+` goes to the end of the string, at which point the...

Comment: ...regex engine backtracks character-by-character until it finds As, then goes to the end-of-string again, then backtracks again until it finds 'End Type'. Note that you probably want `\s+` where you've used `\s` since there may be extra whitespace (more than one character). you *could* create a regex that would match all occurrences, repeatedly (untested): `Type\s+[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(?:\s+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\s+As\s+\S+)+\s+End`. But you wouldn't be able to extract the values from the group that matched repeatedly (at best, you could get the last (or maybe first, depending on the engine) occurrence).

Comment: ...and having just read Sina's answer, which has a regex similar to the one I came up with, I see that you get exactly that: the last capture only.

Answer (score 1):

You've presented two different problems.

The first is, roughly, "can I write a regex to match this thing", the answer is yes. For simplicity I've used `\w` instead of `[a-zA-Z0-9]`:

```
Public\s+Type\s+(\w+)\s+((\w+)\s+As\s+(\w+)\s*('.*\s*)?)+End\s+Type
```

The next is "how can I parse out the properties" and the answer to that is, as written in the comments: don't use a single regex. First, use a regex which captures only the definitions:

```
Public\s+Type\s+\w+\s+(.*?)End\s+Type
```

This uses a the reluctant quantifier `*?` so that the regex won't gobble up `End Type` and the `DOTALL` flag so that you can match several lines. From this match, you take group `1` and repeatedly `find` the following:

```
^\s+(\w+)\s+.*$
```

Group `1` from this match will be your property name.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regexp to match the whole thing:

```
Public\s+Type\s+(?<tname>[\w]+)\s+((?<pname>[\w]+)\s+As\s+(?<ptype>[\w]+)\s+)+End\s+Type
```

Note that it uses named groups for easier access to matched content. Therefore after the whole content is matched, the group named `tname` matches the class type, the group named `pname` matches the property name, and the group named `ptype` matches the corresponding properties type.

Here's its live demo:

http://regexr.com?300l0

Comment: Unfortunately, this is incorrect. The nested group will only contain one of the matches. In order to get all of them, you'll have to extract the whole type definition first and iterate.

Comment: @beerbajay The nested group is not important, one should look for **named** groups. The groups named as `pname` will contain the property names. In many regex engines they can also be referred to as `${pname}`.

Comment: Sina - per your link, and beerbajay's comment, I see that it is only capturing the last 3rd  attribute ("Coupon"), but not the other two ("Cusip" and "Issuer").

Comment: @BigAl You should iterate through the named matches, unfortunately the live demo does not show them properly, but they are indeed matched. You can check it in Expresso for example. This is the code to iterate through named matches in C#, there should be an equivalent one in your language of choice too:
`foreach(Capture capt in new Regex("regexPat").Match("inputString").Groups["pname"].Captures) {
    Console.WriteLine(capt.Value);
}`